# How to apply "@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)" to reposition a HTML element with no ID?

Tags: html, css, anki

I'm trying to make it so if the screen goes <500px wide then "margin-top: 5px" is added to this code. But I don't know what part to encapsulate with the @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){} in order to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-style: hidden; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b id="tags-container">{{Tags}}</b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
/* TAGS */
kbd {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 0.0rem 0.1rem !important;
  margin: 1px !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1.5px !important;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
   word-break: break-all;
}


/* Tag Becomes More Visible On Hover */
kbd:hover { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.2s ease; }


/* Tag Colors */
kbd:nth-of-type(1n+0) { border-color: #fc00ff; color: #fc00ff;}
kbd:nth-of-type(2n+0) { border-color: #03A9F4; color: #03A9F4;}
kbd:nth-of-type(3n+0) { border-color: #FF0000; color: #FF0000;}
kbd:nth-of-type(4n+0) { border-color: #faed27; color: #faed27;}
kbd:nth-of-type(5n+0) { border-color: #FF9933; color: #FF9933}
kbd:nth-of-type(6n+0) { border-color: #ff6ec7; color: #ff6ec7; }
kbd:nth-of-type(7n+0) { border-color: #8ffcff; color: #8ffcff; }
kbd:nth-of-type(8n+0) { border-color: #ff009a; color: #ff009a; }
kbd:nth-of-type(9n+0)  { border-color: #39ff14; color: #39ff14; }
kbd:nth-of-type(10n+0) { border-color: #1b03a3; color: #1b03a3; }

/* Tag Mobile Adjustments */
.mobile kbd { opacity: .9; margin: 1px !important; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px !important; margin-top: 5px !important;}
.mobile #tags-container {line-height:0.6rem; margin-left: 0px; }
```

Comment: You can reposition element by class or by tag itself, e.g. `table {margin-top: 5px}` although that would affect all tables in your page. Perhaps the parent element has an ID? You can then use `#ParentID table {}`...

Comment: So I tried "@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {table {margin-top: 5px !important;}}" which hasn't worked, I've also tried assigning an ID by doing "<table class= "TagBox" style="width: 100%; border-style: hidden; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left;">" in HTML, then "@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {TagBox {margin-top: 5px !important;}}" which hasn't worked either

Comment: When you open your page in a browser, right-click on the table and select "Inspect element" from the pop-up menu (Chrome/Opera, may be called differently in other browsers). Then in the inspector check/uncheck your styles and see if anything fixes your problem.